# need assistance with validation for my calculator

Tags: java

This is my calculator and file reader that I have created. But when I enter the file name for my program to read it reads the file which is a text document containing 24 sums for example "10 10 +". However my program only reads about 11 of them and then returns an error saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at Calculator.main(Calculator.java:104)
```

What am I missing to be able to fix the error? Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Calculator {


    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        String option;
        while(true){
            Scanner scanner3 = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please input the letter K for keyboard or F for file entry:");
            option=scanner3.nextLine();      

            switch(option) 
            {

            case "K":
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Please enter an expression:");
                String line = scanner.nextLine();

                if (line.equals(""))
                {
                    System.out.println("Calculator Closing");
                    System.exit(0);

                }

                char letter;
                String [] elements = line.split(" ");
                double number1 = 0, number2 = 0;

                if (elements.length == 3)           // 3 elements entered validation
                {

                    try{

                        number1 = Double.parseDouble(elements[0]);
                        number2 = Double.parseDouble(elements[1]);
                    }

                    catch (NumberFormatException e) {

                        System.out.println("Error");
                    }


                    if (elements[2].equals("-"))            //validation for when the expressions are entered
                    {
                        System.out.println("Result as follows:" + (number1 - number2));
                    }
                    else if (elements[2].equals("/"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Result as follows:" + (number1 / number2));
                    }
                    else if (elements[2].equals("*"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Result as follows:" + (number1 * number2));
                    }
                    else if (elements[2].equals("+"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Result as follows:" + (number1 + number2));
                    }


                }
                else if(elements.length != 3){          //validation to check that all 3 elements have been entered
                    System.out.println("Invalid number of elements entered");



                }
                break;              // separates the code
            case  "F":
                try{ 


                    System.out.println("Please enter the filename:");
                    Scanner file = new Scanner (System.in);
                    String filename = file.nextLine();
                    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(filename));    // creates a scanner which scans from a file


                    boolean value = true;
                    while (value){
                        while ( s.hasNext() ) {

                            line = s.nextLine();        // reads the next line of text from the file

                            String [] fileinput = line.split(" ");
                            double expression1 = 0, expression2 = 0;

                            try{

                                expression1 = Double.parseDouble(fileinput[0]);
                                expression2 = Double.parseDouble(fileinput[1]);
                            }

                            catch (NumberFormatException e) {

                                System.out.println("error");
                            }
                            if (fileinput[2].equals("-"))
                            {
                                System.out.println("Result as follows:" + (expression1 - expression2));
                            }
                            else if (fileinput[2].equals("/"))
                            {
                                System.out.println("Result as follows:" + (expression1 / expression2));
                            }
                            else if (fileinput[2].equals("*"))
                            {
                                System.out.println("Result as follows:" + (expression1 * expression2));
                            }
                            else if (fileinput[2].equals("+"))
                            {
                                System.out.println("Result as follows:" + (expression1 + expression2));
                            }


                        }
                        System.out.println("\nEOF");            // Outputs the End Of File message
                        value = false;      
                    }
                }
                catch(FileNotFoundException ef) {
                    System.out.println("Error, please enter a correct file name.");
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("invalid letter entered");

            }           
        }
    }}
```

Comment: check the length of `fileinput` array .

Comment: Make sure your file is formatted correctly. Also you should do `.split("\\s+");` instead of `.split(" ");`

Comment: the file that i want my program to read from is a text document containing this :

Comment: 44 3 +
9.99 + 0.09
12 0 *
. 10 -
10.2 2 *
12 4 /
66.1 0.12 -
.0 99.10 +
300 4.0 +
* 20 10 /
10 20
5.2 +
1 2 &
100 139 -
- 80 2
9 5 2
4 / 3
3 A -
200.5 10 *
2 * 4
8 2 *
10 20 -
8 16 /
-4 12 +
+ 4 2
x y z

Comment: @Whitaker96 `fileinput` array haven't 3 elements .`fileinput = line.split(" ");` so `fileinput[2]` gives you a error .can you show your file content with line separates

Comment: can you edit your question to show the input file as is?

Answer (score 0):

I test your code with my own file text with one post fix operation in each line , it work without Exception (without problem), you should check your file if there are some mistakes in your operations input.

But there are some remarks in your code:
-You should use one Scanner for each source for example `System.in` or `new File("name of file")`. 
-For Scanner from Keyboard (`System.in`), it's recommended to use a static Scanner variable like: `private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);`.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is missing one posible input at the line which it tries to read. That means your `String [] fileinput` will not contain 3 elements at the line that fails to print. I took the liberty to divide your input in groups of 3:

```
44 3 +
9.99 + 0.09
12 0 *
. 10 -
10.2 2 * 
12 4 / 
66.1 0.12 -
.0 99.10 +
300 4.0 +
* 20 10
/ 10 20
5.2 + 1
2 & 100
139 - -
80 2 9
5 2 4
/ 3 3
A - 200.5
10 * 2
* 4 8
2 * 10
20 - 8
16 / -4
12 + +
4 2 x
y z
```

You can clearly see by the last line that there is 1 input missing. The exception will be thrown when you call `fileinput[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here, this will solve your problem.

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String option;
        while (true) {
            Scanner scanner3 = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please input the letter K for keyboard or F for file entry:");
            option = scanner3.nextLine();

            switch (option) {

                case "K":
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Please enter an expression:");
                    String line = scanner.nextLine();

                    if (line.equals("")) {
                        System.out.println("Calculator Closing");
                        System.exit(0);

                    }

                    char letter;
                    String[] elements = line.split(" ");
                    double number1 = 0,
                     number2 = 0;

                    if (elements.length == 3) // 3 elements entered validation
                    {

                        try {

                            number1 = Double.parseDouble(elements[0]);
                            number2 = Double.parseDouble(elements[1]);
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

                            System.out.println("Error");
                        }

                        switch (elements[2]) {
                            //validation for when the expressions are entered
                            case "-":
                                System.out.println("Result as follows:" + (number1 - number2));
                                break;
                            case "/":
                                System.out.println("Result as follows:" + (number1 / number2));
                                break;
                            case "*":
                                System.out.println("Result as follows:" + (number1 * number2));
                                break;
                            case "+":
                                System.out.println("Result as follows:" + (number1 + number2));
                                break;
                        }

                    } else if (elements.length != 3) {          //validation to check that all 3 elements have been entered
                        System.out.println("Invalid number of elements entered");

                    }
                    break;              // separates the code
                case "F":
                    try {

                        System.out.println("Please enter the filename:");
                        Scanner file = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String filename = file.nextLine();
                        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(filename));    // creates a scanner which scans from a file

                        boolean value = true;
                        while (value) {
                            while (s.hasNext()) {

                                line = s.nextLine();        // reads the next line of text from the file

                                String[] fileinput = line.split(" ");
                                double expression1 = 0, expression2 = 0;

                                try {
                                    expression1 = Double.parseDouble(fileinput[0]);
                                    expression2 = Double.parseDouble(fileinput[1]);
                                    switch (fileinput[2]) {
                                        case "-":
                                            System.out.println("Result as follows:" + (expression1 - expression2));
                                            break;
                                        case "/":
                                            System.out.println("Result as follows:" + (expression1 / expression2));
                                            break;
                                        case "*":
                                            System.out.println("Result as follows:" + (expression1 * expression2));
                                            break;
                                        case "+":
                                            System.out.println("Result as follows:" + (expression1 + expression2));
                                            break;
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    System.out.println("Syntax error in the expression - \"" + line + "\". Proceeding to next expression.");
                                }
                            }
                            System.out.println("\nEOF");            // Outputs the End Of File message
                            value = false;
                        }
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException ef) {
                        System.out.println("Error, please enter a correct file name.");
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("invalid letter entered");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

***If this works, kindly mark it as accepted.***